# Edit in configuration file of gitlab and bitbuket by git

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab

I can edit in the configuration file that contains the username,password  and github email using git with

```
git config --global -e
```

OR

```
git config --global --edit
```

or in the `.gitconfig` file

How can I edit the `gitlab` and `bitbucket` config files to contain a username, password, and email, and then where do I save it in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found three ways to do this.
First, delete the configuration's username and password.
Run this command in git

```
cmdkey /delete:git:https://gitlab.com
```

If you want to delete bitbucket configuration write in git commandline

```
cmdkey /delete:git:https://bitbucket.org
```

Then, in the next push, you will be prompted for your GitLab OR bitbucket
username/password

---

The second way, show  windows `Credential Manager` by git

```
rundll32 keymgr, KRShowKeyMgr
```

See this gif image[image: configuration gitlab edit]

---

**Finally** edit in configuration file traditionally with  `Credential Manager` see this gif image
[image]

I hope this answer help you.

Comment: So it was a credential helper issue as I mentioned in my answer, then. +1

Comment: I vote to your answer , your answer help me to make the final solution thanks @VonC

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where that configuration is, but all you need to do in Windows is make sure you have set the right credential helper to cache your credentials:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Then, at the first push, you will be prompted for your GitLab username/password.
Once entered, they will be cached in the Windows Credential Manager, and never asked for directly again.